# Why is my code returning "Cannot read property ' ' of undefined"?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to make an array from information in an external json file that is "rolled up" into an array of arrays of objects.

```
var their_name;
$.getJSON('data.json', function(json) {
    json.results.forEach(function(item){
        details["byPop"][item.our_switch_name][item.their_asn]['name'] = item.their_name;
        if(!('ports' in details["byPop"][item.our_switch_name][item.their_name])) {
            details["byPop"][item.our_switch_name][item.their_name]['ports'] = []
        }

        details["byPop"][item.our_switch_name][item.their_name]['ports'].push(item)        
    })   
})
```

I expect to see an array that stores data by pop -> by switch -> by ASN -> by name -> by ports of company however I'm being given the error of Cannot read property 'name of switch' of undefined

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. Please take the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) (and get a badge). Taking the tour and reading about [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) in the help center will provide all the information you need.

Comment: In the mean time, `console.log(item)` within the `forEach()`. There is a high probability that one or more of them are not what you expect.

Comment: That's a lot of subscripting. Not surprising that you get undefined at some point. Lodash has a _.get() functions that ... won't help too much, but at least doesn't crash your code when you don't get what you expect.

Comment: Sorry, looked at your question again. You're assigning something to a deeply nested variable, so use \_.set instead of \_.get: `_.set(details, ["byPop", item.our_switch_name, item.their_asn, 'name'],  item.their_name). https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#set

Answer (score 0):

This might help if you can figure out how to import [lodash](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.11#set).

```
var their_name;
$.getJSON('data.json', function(json) {
    json.results.forEach(function(item){
        item.their_name.ports = item.their_name.ports || []
        item.their_name.ports.push(item)
        _.set(details, ["byPop",item.our_switch_name,item.their_asn,'name'],
              item.their_name)
    })   
})
```